# Generate Joi Schema from Typescript types/interfaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, joi

I want to generate some joi schema object from Typescript types or interfaces. In my initial searching I found some things that do the opposite (generate Typescript types/interfaces from joi schemas), and `ts-interface-builder` + `ts-interface-checker` that offer some ability to create runtime checkers based on Typescript types/interfaces but were still lacking in feature support, and a whole bunch of gnarly things using classes and decorators around props/methods to accomplish this.

Is there something out there to generate such joi schemas? Or a more mature alternative for runtime checking of interfaces/types? (Useful when pulling from a database and ensuring that the response from a DB is in the correct structure)

EDIT: I guess there's a pretty good thread about this kind of problem on [this io-ts github issue](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/issues/318).

Comment: Typescript is not a run-time language. all typescript are stripped when it get compiled to JS. What is wrong with JOI? I've used it in commercial level with typescript projects and use JOI always to validate the schema

Comment: I think [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) falls under the category of alternatives with runtime checking.

Comment: @MonteCristo I understand that Typescript interfaces and types get transpiled away. There's nothing wrong with JOI, I'd just like to have some runtime check of some unknown object structure (from a database, for example) and be able to check at runtime that it conforms to a Typescript interface. I'd rather write Typescript first rather than JOI first.

Comment: Joi schemas are more strict then TS types, maybe it is better to generate TS types from schemas :]

Comment: @felixmosh Couldn't it be easier then to generate joi schemas from TS types? Basically I just need objects with properties of types and certain fields are required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found something that works to my satisfaction for this: [typescript-is](https://github.com/woutervh-/typescript-is).

1. Swap out what typescript compiler you're using to [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript). Instead of calling `tsc`, call `ttsc`.
2. Add the following to `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // Rest of ts config options...
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "typescript-is/lib/transform-inline/transformer"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

3. `$ npm install ttypescript typescript-is`
4. Now you can add the following to your code:

```js
import { is, assertType } from 'typescript-is'

interface SomeInterfaceOrType {
    aString: string
}

// To do a simple boolean check, do the following:
const nonConformingObj = { somethingOutOfLeftField: 42 }
const conforms = is<SomeInterfaceOrType>(nonConformingObj) // false

// Or to get better details on what's wrong, do the following
const anotherNonConformer: unknown = { aString: 1337 }
try {
    assertType<SomeInterfaceOrType>(anotherNonConformer)
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message) // logs: "validation failed at anotherNonConformer.aString: expected a string"
}
```

At compile time, the `is<T>()` and `assertType<T>()` calls will be transformed into working runtime checks. Not necessarily a JOI schema, but still pretty neat, and definitely good enough for my use case.